# How to search for a range of values within an array C#

Tags: c#, arrays, search

I'm still new to C# and I got stuck on one of functionality in my code. I cannot get it to return the values in 'case6', search for age within range (min-max), everything else works fine. What's wrong there?

```
class Buss
{
    private string name = "minibuss";
    public int[] passengers = new int[9];
    public int passengerNum;

    public void Run()  //that´s the menu, you fill in age and then could go through array with other options
    {
        Console.WriteLine("THE miniBUSS SIMULATOR");

        int temp = 0;
        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Choose an alternative (starting with 1 ;-))");
            Console.WriteLine("1. Fill in pass");
            Console.WriteLine("2. Print passengers age");
            Console.WriteLine("3. Show total age of all passanger");
            Console.WriteLine("4. Average age of passsangers");
            Console.WriteLine("5. Who´s oldest");
            Console.WriteLine("6. Show passangers within range of years");
            Console.WriteLine("7. Sort passangers by age");
            Console.WriteLine("Hit 0 to exit\n");
            temp = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            switch (temp)
            {
                case 1:
                    add_passenger();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    print_buss();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    calc_total_age();
                    break;
                case 4:
                    calc_average_age();
                    break;
                case 5:
                    max_age();
                    break;
                case 6:
                    find_age();
                    break;
                case 7:
                    sort_buss();
                    break;
                case 0:
                    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue");
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Use number between 0 and 7");
                    break;
            }
        } while (temp != 0);
    }

    public void add_passenger()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < passengers.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Age of passenger {0}", i);
            if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out int result) && result >= 0 && result <= 122)
            {
                passengers[i] = result;
            }
            else
            {
                i--;
                Console.WriteLine("Max age is 122");
            }
        }
    }

    public void print_buss()
    {
        foreach (int temp in passengers)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(temp);
        }
    }

    public void calc_total_age()
    {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < passengers.Length; i++)
        {
            sum += passengers[i];
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Total age is " + sum);
    }

    public void calc_average_age()
    {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < passengers.Length; i++)
        {
            sum += passengers[i];
        }
        int avr = sum / passengers.Length;

        Console.WriteLine("Avarage age is " + avr);
    }

    public void max_age()
    {
        int max = passengers.Max();
        Console.WriteLine(max);
    }

    public void find_age()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Write the lower limit for your range: ");
        int keyMin = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());                      // say 10
        Console.WriteLine("Write the highest value for your range: ");
        int keyMax = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());                      // ex. 30 so range is 10 - 30 

        for (int i = 0; i < passengers.Length; i++)            
        {
            if (passengers[i] >=  keyMin && passengers[i] <= keyMax)   

//I´ve tried different options for that loop but without succes, do I
// need to call sort_buss() method first?

            {
                Console.WriteLine("Those are the passangers within range: " + i);
            }
            break;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Nothing to return\n");   //That´s what program returns each time
    }

    public void sort_buss()
    {
        int max = passengers.Length - 1;

        for (int i = 0; i < max; i++)
        {
            int nrLeft = max - i;

            for (int j = 0; j < nrLeft; j++)
            {
                if (passengers[j] > passengers[j + 1])
                {
                    int temp = passengers[j];
                    passengers[j] = passengers[j + 1];
                    passengers[j + 1] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < passengers.Length; i++)
        Console.WriteLine("\n Passengers sorted by age ", passengers[i]);
    }
}

class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var minbuss = new Buss();
        minbuss.Run();
        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Imo, Break; is a typo from copy pasting thing around. As an improvement you should decouple the searching from people from the displaying, this way if there are multiple result you don't display "Those are the passangers: A ;Those are the passangers: B; Those are the passangers: C", but something like "Those are the passangers: A, B ,C"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to put off break wich breaks the for loop:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < passengers.Length; i++)            
    {
        if (passengers[i] >=  keyMin && passengers[i] <= keyMax)   

        {
            Console.WriteLine("Those are the passangers within range: " + i);
        }
   ---> //break;
    }
```